# Swift Firebase -How can I verify the `PhoneAuthCredential` and keep the user currently signed in with their current email uid

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

Users sign into my app with email authentication. Once inside they can browse and search for different things. But if the user wants to post they have to verify their phone number (if they don't want to post their phone number isn't necessary).

The phone number and sms process works fine but once I authenticate the `PhoneAuthCredential` the uid associated with the email that the user is currently signed in with is replaced with the uid generated from the phone credential. This creates a situation where an entirely new user is inside the app and because of this they don't have access to any of their data (anything associated with the uid from the email).

[image]

Basically the `Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid` was initially the email's uid and now the `Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid` would be the phone's uid

**How can I verify the `PhoneAuthCredential` and keep the user currently signed in with their current email uid?**

```
var emailUid: String? // a6UVVWWN4CeTCLwvkn...
var verificationId: String?
var phoneUid: String? // tUi502DnKlc19U14xSidP8

// 1. user signs into the app with their email address and their uid is a6UVVWWN4CeTCLwvkn...
Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: emailTextField.text!, password: self.passwordTextField.text!, completion: { 
    (authDataResult: AuthDataResult?, error) in

    self.emailUid = authDataResult?.user.uid  // a6UVVWWN4CeTCLwvkn...         
})

// 2. user goes to post something but before they can post they have to verify their phone number
PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumberTextfield.text!, uiDelegate: nil) {
    (verificationID, error) in

    guard let verificationID = verificationID else { return }

    self.verificationId = verificationID
}

// 3. sms code is sent to user's phone and they enter it
let credential = PhoneAuthProvider.provider().credential(withVerificationID: verificationId!, verificationCode: smsTextField.text!)

// 4. now VERIFY sms code by signing the user in with the PhoneAuthCredential
Auth.auth().signInAndRetrieveData(with: credential, completion: {
    (authDataResult, error) in

    self.phoneUid = authDataResult?.user.uid // tUi502DnKlc19U14xSidP8 this is now the current user's uid

    // 5. save phoneNumber and verificationId to the user's uid ref associated with the EMAIL address
    var dict = [String: Any]()
    dict.updateValue(verificationId!, forKey: "verificationId")
    dict.updateValue(phoneNumberTextfield.text!, forKey: "phoneNumber")
    dict.updateValue(self.phoneUid!, forKey: "phoneUid")

    if Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid == self.emailUid! {

        // THIS WILL NEVER RUN
        let emailUidRef = Database.database().reference().child("users").child(emailUid!)
        emailUidRef?.updateChildValues(dict)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can link the two accounts together using [Firebase Authentication's account linking](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/account-linking). As that documentation says:

> Complete the sign-in flow for the new authentication provider up to, **but not including**, calling one of the `FirebaseAuth.signInWith` methods.

So you skip [`signInAndRetrieveData(with: credential)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#sign-in-the-user), but instead call `User.linkAndRetrieveData(with: credential)`. Once the accounts are linked, you can sign in with either of them to get the "combined" authenticated user.

Comment: Works great. Can you add one thing to your answer though. When trying to access 'linkAndRetrieveData' I kept trying Auth.auth().linkAndRetrieveData then realized it's on the User property: Auth.auth().currentUser?.linkAndRetrieveData(with: ..). The next person might incorrectly keep trying to access it the way I initially did. Thanks for the help!